# How to get handle on current object with a React function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use a React class component, I can easily get a handle on the current object with `this` and pass it to other functions which can then execute methods in the original component.  So this works nicely:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class PrintClass extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        executeRequestElsewhere(this)
    }

    print() {
        console.log("called back to class component ...")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Test Calling Method on Me
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function executeRequestElsewhere(caller) {
    caller.print()
}
```

What is the equivalent to `this` in the above for a React function component?   Is it a ref or do I have to use `bind` or something else?

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Running effect")
        // What do I use for this?
        executeRequestElsewhere2(this)
    }, [])

    const print = () => {
        console.log("please call me :-) ...")
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Function Component
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyComponent

function executeRequestElsewhere2(caller) {
    caller.print()
}
```

My reason for doing this is I have an external function to manage execution of actions for some components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional components don't have instances, but are just *plain functions*. With class components, functions associated with the component are usually defined on the prototype; with functional components, functions associated with the component are usually declared inline in the function body, perhaps in combination with `useCallback`.

For your case, `print` is declared in the function body, so you should pass it to the external function for it to call:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Running effect")
    executeRequestElsewhere2(print)
}, [])
```

and

```
function executeRequestElsewhere2(print) {
    print()
}
```

If you had multiple functions to pass externally, you could pass an object containing all the functions, eg:

```
executeRequestElsewhere2({ print, someOtherFn1, someOtherFn2 })
```

```
function executeRequestElsewhere2(fns) {
    fns.print()
    fns.someOtherFn2()
}
```

Comment: Okay - so it looks like I lose something in this case by using Function components.

Comment: Well, we don't know the specifics of your use case, but the only thing you "lose" is the ability to do something you *probably* shouldn't have been doing in the first place. In React you generally don't call a component's function externally, that's not how the state and lifecycle of a component should be controlled. So that external function you mention that's calling a bunch of component's methods, that's almost certainly not the right approach (though as I said, without specifics we can't confirm or suggest a proper way to handle your use case).

Comment: True.  It's convenient for me to call back to the original component 'instance'. The workaround suggested by @CertainPerformance is quite satisfactory.   However, yes, there is probably a more elegant way I can achieve the same high level outcome in my use case.